# Using NestedRuntimeException and NestedCheckedException

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring in our projects and I came across 2 Spring exception abstract classes: `NestedRuntimeException` that is abstract and extends `RuntimeException` and `NestedCheckedException` that is abstract and extends `Exception`. Those classes provide some util methods to get more information about the exception thrown and are used by Spring for pretty much every Spring exception classes.

I would like to know if you would advice to use those classes for your exception classes in your projects based on Spring, and if yes, do you advice to use it just for specific cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advice for not using them. You can get the same functionality using ExceptionUtils from Apache Commons Lang (org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils) and you would not bind your code so heavily to the Spring Framework - which even if very cool - is an external dependency.

Comment: Ok ExceptionUtils looks interessing and I understand your concern about the heavy coupling, however sometimes we are doing big effort for low coupling (for best practice) with a specific technology but to be honest we know that we won't change the technology :)

Comment: Yes - that is true. However if there is an easily accessible replacement I would definitely go for it ;)

Comment: @EmilienBrigand If my answer was useful for you, then you are always welcomed to upvote it :)

Comment: the response do not really explain why not used those exceptions classes